# Linking two colours with te-form

Tags: て-form, colors

So I read somewhere that you cannot describe an item with two colours using te-form.
eg そのシャツは赤くてしろいです. Just want to verify if it's true, and if so, how would you link them? Would using the noun form of colours be correct? eg そのシャツは赤と白いです。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, it is true combining color adjective with te-form would sound unnatural like そのシャツは赤くて白いです. It sounds like *the shirt is red and white*, which is not possible. That said, practically, it may well be understood as *Red and white are used for the shirt (there are red part and white part in the shirt)*.

Using noun form is fine, but you should use nouns for both: そのシャツは赤と白です.

My impression is that usually the description is more specific.

- そのシャツは白地に赤のロゴ入りです The shirt has a red logo with white background.
- そのシャツは青と黄色の縞模様です The shirt has blue and yellow stripes.

`Color A と Color B` is more likely when it is understood how they are used.